# Android - Removing Multiple Items From List View

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, items

**Problem Solved:**

For anyone in the future who has this problem, I found this this nice tutorial: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-delete-multiple-selected-items-listview-tutorial/

and re-adapted it to my own use. I didn't use the MultiChoiceModeListener with the ActionBar, I used my original OnClickListener.

Also I couldn't get their highlighting from the xml to work so I kept my original highlighting code. There was a problem with the color not disappearing after I removed the items so I ended up iterating through all of my View's and setting them to transparent after each removal. Not the most efficient way, but it works.

**Original Question:**

I've been trying to select multiple items by clicking them with a ListView ListView and then delete by clicking a button. I've made a array adapter so I can format my items. However the problem is whenever I delete an item(s), the only ones that gets deleted are the items in the end of my list.

I've looked at other people who had similar problems, but unfortunately to no avail. I'm stump and need some help.

My Fragment that uses the ListView:

```
public class SellEquipment extends Fragment {
ListView listview;
String[] itemname ={
         "Safari",
         "Camera",
         "Global",
         "World",
         "Test"
         };

ArrayList<String> list;
private EquipmentViewAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<Integer> sellList;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sellequipment_activity, container, false);
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String item : itemname) {
        list.add(item);
    }


    sellList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    adapter = new EquipmentViewAdapter(getActivity(), itemname, list);

    Button sellBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sellBtn);

    sellBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        /*  SparseBooleanArray itemPos = listview.getCheckedItemPositions();
            int itemCount = listview.getCount();
            for (int i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (itemPos.get(i)) {
                    adapter.remove(list.get(i));
                }
            }
            listview.clearChoices();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/

            for (int position : sellList) {
                list.remove(position);
            }
            sellList.clear();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listview.clearChoices();
        }
    });
    listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            //String SelectedItem = itemname[position];
            if (!sellList.contains(position)) {
                listview.setItemChecked(position, true);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                sellList.add(position);
            } else {
                listview.setItemChecked(position, false);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                sellList.remove(Integer.valueOf(position));
            }
            //list.remove(position);
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity().  getApplicationContext(), SelectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return view;
}  
}
```

And here's my adapter:

```
public class EquipmentViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] itemname;
private final List<String> list;

public EquipmentViewAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, ArrayList<String> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, list);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context = context;
    this.itemname = itemname;
    this.list = list;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = view;

    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null);
    }

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView lvl = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView spd = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView rch = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    //@todo get data from array list or 2D array
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); // have the pictured ordered correctly
    lvl.setText("lvl: " + itemname[position]);
    spd.setText("spd: " + itemname[position]);
    rch.setText("rch: " + itemname[position]);
    return rowView;
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm literally pulling my hair out on this!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

change your `sellList` to contain `String`s

```
private ArrayList<String> sellList;

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
    String item = adapter.getItem( position );
    if (!sellList.contains( item )) {
        listview.setItemChecked(position, true);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        sellList.add( item );
    } else {
        listview.setItemChecked(position, false);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        sellList.remove( item );
    }
}
```

then

```
        for (String item : sellList) {
            adapter.remove( item );
        }
        sellList.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listview.clearChoices();
```

Comment: I've changed my code, unfortunately I still have the same problem. Is there anything else that you might need to better asses what's going wrong with my code?

Comment: Darn, I was really hoping that would be the issue. Unfortunately I still have the same problem. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The list you delete from is not the one the adapter is using. When you pass `list` into your adapter it is copied. You need to delete from the list that the adapter is using.

Comment: Yeah thats what I'm sort of seeing also I think. You use "sellList.remove" which only removes an items from a list of Intigers. But what you need to do is remove the ListItem it self. So I'm guessing something like "listview.remove(item)". Have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GfVI-iHGM_Y and see if that helps

Comment: `adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));`, as injecteer wrote.
I can however not identify how items are still removed from the end of the list - At least not from the code that was posted.

Comment: I've tried both ways, unfortunately I still received the same problem. Is there any other code that I can show that could help debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

in onActionItemClicked and switch method:

```
case R.id.selectAll:
    for (int i = 0; i < listView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
       customAdapter.selectAll(i);
       listView.setItemChecked(i, true);
                            }
```

and in the youradapter create:

```
public void selectAll(int i) {
  mSelectedItemsIds.put(i, false);
  }
```